# how to create python package list installed by pip only

Tags: python, pip

and sorry in advance if this question is duplicated.

If I want to create all installed python package list, I can easily create with `pip list` or `pip freeze`.

Some of them are installed by `pip install`, and some of them are installed by OS's package manager like `apt`, `yum`, `pacman`.

Can I create the package list separately? if yes please let me know, thanks.

Comment: You have to use virtual environment for development for each project. Then you can separate packages installed system wide with the help of virtual environment.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I will use virtual environment for each project as you advised but it also would be appreciated if you can let me know the answer of my question.

Answer (score 0):

On Debian based systems using `dpkg -l` you can list all the packages installed, with version, architecture, description. Based on the package manager this would change, if it is a Red hat based system `rpm -qa`.

To get the list of packages that were installed by pip `pip list`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but for me this is not that obvious especially when the pip package name is not corresponding to the OS's package name.
for example, `beautifulsoup4` in pip is `python4-bs4` in apt so I can assume they are the same, but I need to check one by one to see they are obviously the same.